# Draw circle and store in UIImage

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikit, core-graphics

How do I draw a filled circle with core graphics and return it as a UIImage?

I want to do something like the following:

`+ (UIImage*) circleImageWithRadius:(CGFloat)radius fillColor:(UIColor*)clr;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should get you most of the way there: http://www.codza.com/creating-and-drawing-on-a-new-uiimage

Also look at `CGContextFillEllipseInRect`:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html